# Converting base64 string into image in webservice in asp.net with c#

Tags: asp.net

I am using this code to convert base64 string which is coming from android side to image in  websevice's webmethod ...but it is giving me error   "Generic error occurred in GDI+"..

```
        Random r = new Random();
    int n = r.Next();
    string pic = n + ".jpg";
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(picpath);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    String picname = Server.MapPath("FarmImages") + "\\"+pic;
    image.Save(@picname);
```

is it possible that i am using this in webmethod sothat it is giving me error..because this works perfectly in ASP page ...but throwing error in web service..

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: What is picpath?  Is that a string containing the base64, or is it a file path?

Comment: i got error in image.save(@picname) line..here picpath is a string that contains base64.

Answer (score 0):

Which line is the error occurring in?  is it image.Save()?  Does your service process have permissions to write to the folder that you are saving to?

I'm not sure what your error is, but it looks like you are writing your memory stream twice.  this code seems to work for me:

```
string imagestr = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\temp\apng.png"));
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imagestr);
var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
stream.Position = 0;
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
image.Save(@"d:\temp\testout.png");
```

Comment: how i give permission to service process to write in a folder? I am using webservices first time..